# Enable Security CheckBox is not present in the Global Configuration Settings of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have downloaded jenkins for LTS (Long Term Support) and installed all the suggested plugins while installing jenkins. When i goto ManageJenkins -> Global Configuration Settings -> I could not see the Enable Security CheckBox.

I Installed 'Role Based Authorization Strategy' and 'Authorize Project' Plugin in my jenkins and when i try to assign roles for users (which is Manually created by me in jenkins) it shows the following error:

```
 Builds in Jenkins run as the virtual Jenkins SYSTEM user with full Jenkins permissions by default. 
This can be a problem if some users have restricted or no access to some jobs, but can configure others. 
If that is the case, it is recommended to install a plugin implementing build authentication, and to override this default.
    
        ✅ An implementation of access control for builds is present.
        ❌ Access control for builds is possible, but not configured. Configure it in the global security configuration.
```

Any Suggestions from anyone...

Answer (score 2):

Under **ManageJenkins -> Global Configuration Settings**, go to the section "**Access Control for Builds**" and add a Build Authorization.

For example, you could use the following setting:

[image]